# How to disable editing of cells after midnight in googlesheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a google spreadsheet which we use to feed inventory purchase and issue data. The only problem is my staff can manipulate purchased quantity, prices and other variables at a later date. I want that if they enter data in a cell, they cannot edit it post-midnight but I can.

Also, I have filled most of the cells with formula, for example- there is formula in A1:H999, so that when they enter data, it calculates the values in other cells, and suppose my staff has entered data till A1:H500. In this case, the script should work On A1:H500, it should not consider the whole range just because i have filled it with formula. Thanks

Comment: Look at the Arrayformula() function for applying formulas to a range of cells.  For instance, using =arrayformula(if(isblank(A2:A),,B2:B + C2:C) will add cells B and C together in each row where cell A has information.  Providing a sample sheet is helpful to get this worked out.  As for limiting access, I would suggest a script run as a web app under your account.  Create an interface where they can edit data and check against the date of a timestamp cell. If after that date, refuse the edit.

Comment: look at triggers (time based) and the spreadsheetApp permission methods. show us attempts and what is failing.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to limit access to the script to particular hours it's fairly simple. This can be done with one function if written in a clever way or with 2 functions.

Function1 will simply lock the spreadsheet and allow only you to edit by using the [protection class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/protection), then use function2 (or write function1 in a clever way to do different things depending on when it starts) that is triggered at a different time to remove that protection.